# Using 'IF.. ELSE' to change variable and use it in 'form action...'

Tags: php

I've created a test form that uses IF.. ELSE to validate data in a simple form. This works ok and any validation messages or errors are posted to the same page (userform.php) to inform the user of success or otherwise.

What I want to do now is take the user to a different page on successful completion of the form. Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
$errors = array ();

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$password = $_POST ['password'];


if (empty ($firstname) || empty ($lastname) || empty ($email) || empty ($password)) {
$errors [] = "Please complete the form";
}
if (empty($email)) {
$errors [] = "You must enter an email address";
}
if (empty($password)) {
$errors [] = "You must enter a password";
}
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE){
$errors[] = "Please enter a valid email address";
}
}
if (!empty ($errors)) {
foreach ($errors as $error) {
echo '<strong>', $error ,'</strong><br />';
$result = "userform.php";
 }
} else {
$result = "confirm.php";
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $result ?>" method="post">
```

The idea is that the users success or otherwise in completing the form changes the $result variable which is used in the form action. The above code doesn't work, so how would I do it? 
Is it even possible?

Comment: how doesn't it work? it gets redirected but no values passed? doesn't get redirected at all?

Comment: You _are_ aware that since PHP is a preprocessor, the form will need to be submitted once to validate everything and set the correct action, and then once again to post to said action?

Comment: sorry! adding the $result variable in the locations above just see's the user redirect to confirm.php, whether they've entered correct details in the form or not.

Comment: I am not sure to understand..do you want just to redirect user or to repost data in another page after validation?

Comment: You mean that even if there are errors, it gets redirected to confirm.php instead of userform.php?

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom - no, I'm not aware of that. This is basically my first foray into php.
@ Mika A - actually, both. I'm really new at this, so maybe naively I'm thinking that if the form validates and the 'form action' is changed to confirm.php then the data from the form will be posted to that page too?

Comment: Then one thing you should learn right now about PHP is that as it is a preprocessor, it cannot do any work once the user has been presented with the page - it resides exclusively on the server side, and runs before the page is even sent to the user. If you want to be able to change things as the user is using the page, you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: OK, I was aware of that, was presuming I was ignorant, as I mostly am at this point. I think the issue with this code was as per CodeCaster's reply below - the form has to be submitted twice to work in order to resolve entirely. Sorry, I'm not being very clear, but think it's obvious that I'm out of my depth!

Answer (score 1):

instead of "form action=" at the bottom:

```
<?php
include($result);
?>
```

Comment: Yes i think it's the best solution and you can continue to have $_POST variable using this solution, instead of redirectting via http

Comment: @Jorge Pinho - thanks for the tip, but I'm afraid it doesn't work - on submit I get 'Forbidden' error! :(

Comment: @MikaA. You cant use the same page. Use a page as the container, and then you have "sucess" and "form" as separate .php

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you want it to work like so:

1. User fills form
2. User submits form
3. Form submission goes to `userform.php`

   1. If all values validate, continue to `confirm.php`
   2. If not, return to `userform.php`

If that's the case, I don't think you want to change the form action: that would require that the user re-submit the form. Instead, use a HTTP redirect to send them to `confirm.php`:

```
header("Location: confirm.php");
```

... or if you wanna be really by-the-book about it:

```
header("Status: 303 See Other");
header("Location: http://exampel.com/confirm.php"); // according to the protocol,
                                                    // `Location` headers should be full URLs
```

---

```
<?php
/* ... */
if (!empty ($errors)) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo '<strong>', $error ,'</strong><br />';
     }
     ?>
         <form action="userform.php" method="post">
     <?php
} else {
    header("Location: confirm.php");
    // if you need to pass additional information to confirm.php, use a query string:
    // header("Location: confirm.php?var1=".$var1);
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. How/where should I use the 'header' code in my code?

Comment: Added an example; it's not the most beautiful code but it gets the point across.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'header' at all (there's a theme emerging here), but when I drop that in it seems to almost work. 
Whilst the form is incorrectly filled out, it shows the appropriate error messages, but when it's completed correctly I get some PHP errors:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...userform.php:5) in ...userform.php on line 33 / line 34
These are the lines where the header functions appear in the code. Any tips? Thanks for your advice so far :)

Comment: Busy, so I can't explain that, [but s quick SO search can](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+modify+header+information)!

Comment: OK, I'm a douchebag, point taken ;)
However, this works as envisaged above i.e. adding:
header("Location: confirm.php?firstname=$firstname etc");
Then I can output these variables in confirm.php. 
The only drawback I have is that this passes input in a password field as an unencrypted string, but it's really not important for the purposes of what I was trying to do right now. I'll add this as my answer to the question :)

Comment: @Sam Campsall - Don't sweat it; you're not a douche. I on the other hand hadn't considered the fact that one of those fields was a password... if that information (which is going in the query string) is sensitive, or changes server state, make sure you're not vulnerable to [URL manipulation attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL_attack) or to [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

Comment: @Sam Campsall - Oh, and last but not least, don't forget to [vote up useful answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-answers-not-accepted1.png) and to [accept the answer which solved your problem](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-answers-accepted1.png).

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it now, will redirect the user to confirm.php if they submit the form for a second time. You could change your code to this:

```
} else {
    // $result = "confirm.php";
    header("Location: confirm.php");
    exit();
}
```

That way, if everything has been entered, the user will be redirected to confirm.php. But what do you do with the variables if everything is allright? They won't be taken to the new page.

Comment: +1 - Judging by their comment on my answer, this is indeed what @Sam Campsall was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
} else {
   $result = confirm.php;

   foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
     $input.="<input type='hidden' name='$key' value='$val' />";
   }

   $form = "<form method='post' name='confirm' action='confirm.php'>".$input."</form>";
   $script = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.confirm.submit();</script>";

   echo $form.$script;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
empty ($errors)
```

will ALWAYS return empty. That's why you always get:
`$result = 'confirm.php';`

Check [return values here](https://www.php.net/empty)

Also, I don't think you can do this easily. Instead, why don't you just create a check.php or whatever to check the variables/check for errors, etc. Then do whatever you want (redirect back to the form-filling page or proceeding to confirm.php page.

Answer (score -2):

The whole idea is wrong. You have to fix 2 issues in your code.

## 1. A major one. Learn to properly indent nested code blocks!

It's impossible to read such an ugly mass with no indents.

**2. A minor one.**

I see no use of confirmation page here. What are you gonna do on that page? And from where you're going to get form values?

It seems you have to either use just simple Javascript code to show a confirmation or store entered data into session

And, I have to say, that show a confirmation page for simply a feedback form is quite uncommon practice.

So, I think you really need only one form action and only thing to ccare is properly filled form

```
<?  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST ['email'];
  $password = $_POST ['password'];

  $errors = array();
  if (empty ($firstname) || empty ($lastname) || empty ($email) || empty ($password)) {
    $errors [] = "Please complete the form. All fields required.";
  }
  if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE){
    $errors[] = "Please enter a valid email address";
  }    
  if (!$errors) {  
    // do whatever you wish to this data
    // and then redirect to whatever address again
    // the current one is a default
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
  $form['fiestname'] = $form['lasttname'] = $form['email'] = $form['password'] = '';  
}
include 'form.tpl.php';
?>
```

while in the form.tpl.php file you have your form fields, entered values and conditional output of error messages

```
<? if ($errors): ?>
  <? foreach($errors as $e): ?>
<div class="err"><?=$e?></div>
  <? endforeach ?>
<? endif ?>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value=<?=$form['firstname']>

... and so on
```

Comment: 1) sorry about the ugly code - this is more about not being used to stackoverflow.
2) This is my first php effort, so your second point doesn't really help.

Comment: LOL, sure, it's my answer makes you trouble :)

Comment: Sure, well your initial answer looks more helpful now you edited it at least!
I have no problem with you finding my efforts laughable - I'm kindof expecting that - but a pointer in the right direction would be great. 
I'd like to use PHP as opposed to Javascript, as this whole exercise is about me learning some PHP - if you have a link for a tut on sessions then I'm all ears/eyes/whatever!

Comment: +1 to offset the haters that only want exact answers to the exact question asked. Quite a useful post.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel - thanks muchly for the edited reply. I've been away from the computer, but will try it out. Appreciate your time on this.